# Major HDD slowdown after hot swap of another drive

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, performance

Earlier I inserted a SATA drive into a simple one drive backplane I have.  After a "detect hardware changes" the drive appeared, and worked correctly.  Later, I removed it.

Since that time, my primary SATA drive, a Western Digital Caviar Black 640GB, which was never disconnected, is *extremely slow*, on the order of **4.0MB/second maximum transfer rate.**

The first thing I considered is that the drive might be failing, but it passes the DataLifeguard Quick Test and Windows chkdsk.  While this cannot rule out a hardware problem, it indicates against it.

Can my insertion and removal of another SATA drive have reset the connection into some very slow compatibility mode?  How do I fix it?  If that is not the problem, what else could cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure enough, the controller channel had fallen back to PIO from Ultra DMA 5.

The solution was:

1. Find the sub-key for the controller channel within:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E96A-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
   ```
2. Delete `MasterIdDataChecksum` and `SlaveIdDataChecksum`
3. Reboot

Comment: +1 For the smart explanation and for sharing the solution!